# Multiple parallel IIR bandpass filters with different centre frequencies combined into one filter for optimisation... possible?

Tags: filter-design, bandpass, optimization

Before I begin, I have read these already:

- [IIR filter parallelization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8020/iir-filter-parallelization)
- [Concept of combining multiple FIR Filters into 1 FIR filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20194/concept-of-combining-multiple-fir-filters-into-1-fir-filter)

I am processing audio using Csound in a high performance real time environment. One part of my code uses 10 butterworth bandpass filters in parallel, each with a different centre frequency and bandwidth. However, the centre frequencies and bandwidths are all relative to each other. The centre frequency of each filter are set whole number multiples or divisions of the main filter's centre frequency (ie, if main filter has cf of 100Hz, the other filters cfs would be 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 50, 33.333, 25, and 20). The bandwidths of each filter are all a specific division of the associated centre frequency (ie, cf 100 = bw 10, cf 200 = bw 20, etc).

The main centre frequency is not fixed, but seeing as the filter centre frequencies and bandwidths are all relative to the main filters centre frequency and bandwidth, could I design a filter that combines all these filters into one? And most importantly, if I could, would it make any major difference to performance?

My best guess as to how to achieve this would be to combine the filter equations into one. I don't know if this would actually work, but if it did, I don't feel like it would improve the performance by much.

EDIT:

The sample being filtered is rich in harmonic and in-harmonic frequencies. It is borderline noisy, so the sum of the outputs of the BP filters is quite interesting, and the harmonies aren't always perfectly related. This quality I would like to keep.

Comment: what's the order of the individual BPFs?  and what are you trying to do?  filterbank?  graphic EQ?

Comment: 2nd order. What I'm doing is feeding in a rich, borderline noisy sample signal, and filtering out a range of signals that are pretty much harmonically related, hence the integer multiples and divisions of the fundamental. I guess that would be considered a filterbank.

Comment: okay, since a 2nd-order BPF is a mapping of a 1st-order LPF prototype to 2nd-order by this mapping: $$ Q \left( \frac{\omega_0}{s} + \frac{s}{\omega_0} \right) \rightarrow s $$ and **all** 1st-order LPFs are Butterworth, the qualifier "butterworth" does not have meaning.  but Q still is an issue. is this a filterbank (with separate outputs for each 2nd-order BPF) or is it a graphic EQ where the outputs are mixed?  since Q of a BPF is 1-to-1 related to bandwidth in octaves, i would suggest having the same Q for all BPFs and then spacing the center frequencies equally in the log-frequency scale.

Comment: so if we forget about the filters bellow 100Hz, then my example fits the bill. So how do I use this idea to optimise the filters?

Comment: so you want a filterbank?  what are you trying to do with it?  i presume you will be summing each filter output to your overall output, but i also presume that you are doing some processing to each of those filter outputs before summing.  but i don't understand what the processing is or is intended to be.

Comment: What is your sampling rate

Comment: by the way "high performance first order filters at 600Hz" sounds a little ... contradictionary. You sure you're not missing an "M" before the "Hz"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I said it was a high performance real time environment, not that the filters were high performance. There is a vast section of code that has to execute every 30 seconds or so, and this is just a tiny slice of it, so I am trying to make every bit of code as streamline as possible. Also they're second order, not first order. The sample rate can be any of the normal audio rates from 44.1kHz to 96kHz.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson It is an audio project. I have a sort of noisy sample (among other elements that are added to the sample pre-filtering) and my collection of BP filters is filtering a vaguely harmonically related collection of frequencies from the sample. As the frequencies present in the sample vary over time, I am able to get a very interesting, and ever so slightly discordant evolving sound out of it. I get fantastic results, but unfortunately, I cannot afford the processing power that the task requires, so I want to find a way to condense the filter code down

Comment: @IronAttorney I mean, every 30s is not very often, and I really think that at those low rates without any hard realtime restrictions, optimization is really kind of time wasted; narrow down why your system is so slow; it's definitely not because less than 10 second order butterworths at 96kS/s are running. I can do a 51 Tap FIR on my laptop at several dozen Megasamples per second, not even using especially optimized structures.... on a normal PC.

Comment: By the way, how *do* you design a 60Hz wide second order butterworth? For the minimum sample rate you specify, 44100Hz, that's a cutoff at $1.36\cdot10^{-3}$ of the sampling rate; the resulting butterworth would numerically be extremely bad-conditioned; did you run a simulation/z-Domain analysis on the resulting filter? Without investigating much further, I'd say your filter is numerically doomed to perform pretty badly if you don't have a multistage filter approach; you really shouldn't be working at $\ge$44.1kHz sampling rate if your maximum frequency of interest is <700Hz !

Comment: I didn't design it, I used the butterbp opcode in Csound. I am planning on designing my own if I can optimize these filters into one. Having just had a look through the source for this opcode, it doesn't look like their filter breaks from the overall sample rate either. Surely there would be a loss in sound quality if I reduced the sample rate before processing. I thought the general rule in audio is to process signals at higher sample rate's and only reduce the sample rate for the final output

Comment: I also already stated that this was not the only thing happening. This is just a minute slice of the processing going on within the 30second intervals. Every split second of processing time saved is crucial! Having watched how long each element of my process takes, this particular element took quite a long time comparative to most. Hence why I am trying to work out if I can optimize it

Comment: I think, what you need is "IIR filter parallel form". Take a look, for example, to this [IIR filters: parallel and cascade IIR structures](http://www.bores.com/courses/intro/iir/5_para.htm)

Answer (score 1):

So, what I took away from my multirate lectures is:

You don't use IIRs in that case, because the recursive part isn't shareable among multiple filter implementations (being specific to the output of each filter), and hence, you end up with a lot more multipliers than you'd have if you went for a FIR system and removed redundancies. This is especially true for hardware/FPGA implementation, where placing a wire to use a result twice is cheap. You're doing software, so saving a few registers worth of filter taps really won't pay -- you're breaking the linear nature of memory access that way, and that will impose a performance hit that is much, much worse.

In fact, I'd challenge you to look at how you can understand your filter bank as an array of filterbanks with identical filters.

For example, assume that all your BPFs have equally spaced center frequencies $\frac{f_\text{sample}}{N}$. Also, they might have different bandwidths, but since you say they are related to each other, let's assume there's one "maximum bandwidth" that is a multiple of all smaller bandwidths.

Now, implementing a polyphase filterbank ("channelizer") with a BPF of that maximum bandwidth and the constant frequency spacing is very efficient. Basically, it's like taking a single very BPF at full rate, add one FFT, and you get the complexity of the system for up to $N$ channels (note: this is $N-1$ free channels!). Then, take the channels whose bandwidth you'd need to be reduced further. Now, assume these $m<N$ channels all need to be reduced in bandwidth by a factor of $4$, for example. So that's $m$ identical quarterband lowpass filters! Implementing identical filters in hardware is pretty efficient, usually, especially because after the first filterbank, sampling rate might already be reduced (so you can multiplex multipliers); now, you're seemingly doing audio on a PC:

Take these $m$ channels, and just implement individual filters. There's nothing much you can or need to optimize here; assuming this is on something that has a PC-like CPU, caching will keep your filter taps close to CPU registers, and and only the actual samples will need to go through memory buses. Also, not that things like $\frac{1}{M}$ low pass filters are relatively relaxed in transition width requirements, and hence, FIR implementations are short in taps, and thus fast.

As usual in signal processing, decimate whenever possible! The polyphase filterbank might already decimate, but also your $m$ channel low pass filters should do that, too, and in a clever manner (a polyphase lowpass decimator runs at the output, not the input sampling rate!). Not processing samples you don't need is probably reason Nr. 1 that modern DSP is so capable.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! I have to admit my DSP isn't up to scratch enough to keep up with everything you've said from the example onwards, so I'm gonna have to give it a good few reads through :D I haven't actually tried any other filters except the butterworth yet, so I can't rule out the possibility of using an FIR instead, you never know, the results might sound better! I will definitely try some other filters...

Comment: ... So I can glean from what you say that the equally spaced filter CFs will help my ability to optimize, as well as the relative bandwidths. It occurs to me that, because the bandwidths increase identically to the CFs, then my BPFs at 100, 200, 300 Hz CFs can be thought of as HPFs at 95, 190, 285 Hz and LPFs at 105, 210, 315 Hz, which means each of the HP and LP elements also have equally spaced cuttoff frequencies.

Comment: @IronAttorney hm, this is all getting a bit too confusing for a comments section; can't you make a new question about "Efficient implementation of non-uniform filterbank", detailing the center frequencies and bandwidths of those, in a table or so?

Comment: I thought I was still talking about a uniform filterbank. Let's simplify this. In my current filters, the bandwidths increase at the same rate as the centre freqs. For example, the bandwidth is always 10 times smaller than the centre frequency. A re-read of this "Then, take the channels whose bandwidth you'd need to be reduced further. Now, assume these m<Nm<N channels all need to be reduced in bandwidth by a factor of 44, for example." now makes me think that would end up with as many calculations as if they were separate filters. Is that right?

Comment: @IronAttorney the trick is that after your channelizer filterbank, you would have simple, pretty relaxed low-pass filters, that reduce on a $\frac 1N f_\text{sample}$ further to a  $\frac {1}{Nm} f_\text{sample}$ rate. Your original filters would be very narrowband relative to the full sample rate, and hence very long and hence very CPU-intense...

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I follow now. The narrow bandwidth is what I am after

Comment: yes, but your bandwidths aren't all equal. So I say: filter to the widest bandwidth, and decimate. Then filter to narrower bandwidths as needed in a second stage. The resulting filters will both be shorter, because they'd be wider relative to the decimated sampling rate, and also will be running at a lower speed!

Comment: Ok, in my example, we have filter CFs from 100->600Hz, and each filter's BW was CF/10. So, what you're suggesting is to filter the sample through the 600Hz BP, then decimate the sample and filter it through the 500Hz at the lower sample rate, and then presumably separately decimate the original sample for the 400Hz filter and so on, is that correct?

Comment: Hang on, is this what you're talking about? 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling

if so, I don't think this is what I am after. I don't want the output of each filter to necessarily be perfectly harmonically related. The sample is rich and borderline noisy, so the frequency content of the output of each filter is quite interesting, which I want. I thought I had stated about the richness/noisyness of the sample already, but I had only mentioned this in a comment. I will update my question to include the extra details

Comment: No, I'm not talking about undersampling, @IronAttorney.

Comment: My approach is simply first taking the same filter for every of the $c$ CFs,and decimate the resulting $c$ streams to just enough sample rate to fit the biggest bandwidth(in your case, that seems to be 600Hz/10=60Hz);on each of these streams,use a low pass filter to further filter the result to the desired bandwidth.Because the first filterbank reduced the individual sampling rate so much,you're saving very many operations. But, to be honest, at a maximum bandwidth of 60Hz,any pocket calculator can filter your channels,so I really don't know whether we should consider optimization any further.